# Why there is no `Cofunctor` typeclass in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

Monads get `fmap` from `Functor` typeclass. Why comonads don't need a `cofmap` method defined in a `Cofunctor` class?

Comment: That's because a cofunctor is the same as a functor. There's no difference between the two. However, monads and comonads are different. There is such a thing as a contravariant functor though, with a `contramap` method which has the type `Contravariant f => (a -> b) -> f b -> f a`. However, it's not the same as a cofunctor.

Comment: Do you mean "cofunctor" as the dual of a functor (which is just a functor, since it's self-dual), or to mean a functor which is contravariant?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394472/is-cofunctor-an-accepted-term-for-contravariant-functors

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`Functor` is defined as:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

`Cofunctor` could be defined as follows:

```
class Cofunctor f where
    cofmap :: (b -> a) -> (f b -> f a)
```

So, both are technically the same, and that's why `Cofunctor` does not exist. "The dual concept of 'functor in general' is still 'functor in general'".

Since `Functor` and `Cofunctor` are the same, both monads and comonads are defined by using `Functor`. But don't let that make you think that monads and comonads are the same thing, they're not.

A monad is defined (simplifying) as:

```
class Functor m => Monad where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

whether a comonad (again, simplified) is:

```
class Functor w => Comonad where
    extract :: w a -> a
    extend :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b
```

Note the "symmetry".

---

Another thing is a contravariant functor, defined as:

```
import Data.Functor.Contravariant
class Contravariant f where
    contramap :: (b -> a) -> (f a -> f b)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the dual of a functor C -> D a functor D -> C? So the dual of **a** functor isn't the same functor itself, but the dual concept of "functor in general" is still "functor in general". I think I'm just playing semantics, but the language in "a functor is it's self dual" sounds like the claim that individual functor are somehow usable as their own inverse, or something.

Comment: @Ben That more or less shakes out to the formal definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories#Definition

Answer (score 4):

For reference,

```
class Functor w => Comonad w where
  extract :: w a -> a
  duplicate :: w a -> w (w a)
  extend :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b

instance Applicative m => Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

Note that given `extract` and `extend` you can produce `fmap` and `duplicate`, and that given `return` and `>>=` you can produce `fmap`, `pure`, `<*>`, and `join`. So we can focus on just `pure`+`>>=` and `extract`+`extend`.

I imagine you might be looking for something like

```
class InverseFunctor f where
  unmap :: (f a -> f b) -> a -> b
```

Since the `Monad` class makes it easy to "put things in" while only allowing a sort of hypothetical approach to "taking things out", and `Comonad` does something opposed to that, your request initially sounds sensible. However, there is a significant asymmetry between `>>=` and `extend` that will get in the way of any attempt to define `unmap`. Note in particular that the first argument of `>>=` has type `m a`. The second argument of `extend` has type `w a`—*not* `a`.

Comment: we could define an unmap with: "unmap f = extract . f . return" and type signature "unmap :: Monad f, Comonad f => (f a -> f b) -> a -> b"

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you're wrong: there is one!

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-cofunctor