# What is a covariant functor?

Tags: haskell

I would like understand, why for example, the `Maybe` type is a covariant functor?

What does covariant mean?

Please provide an example to clarify.

Comment: Covariant functors are described [here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/11/covariance-contravariance) (FPComplete.com). There's an example using `Maybe`.

Comment: This is a question about mathematics primarily. All `Functor`s in Haskell are covariant. A contravariant functor would be a type `f` with a function `contramap :: (a -> b) -> f b -> f a` - note that the resulting function, compared to `fmap`, has the arrow "reversed". [This does exist in Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.5/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html), but isn't nearly so ubiquitous as the (covariant) `Functor`.

Comment: `This is a question about mathematics primarily` that what makes Haskell scared to learn. I am not an mathematician but I would like to understand it. The question is, how to explain to a not mathematician?

Comment: @zero_coding I wouldn't say it's about mathematics really. The concept does indeed derive from mathematics (specifically, category theory), but you really don't need to know the maths to understand the concept. I've found this to be true of Haskell more generally as well.

Comment: To clarify - I complete agree with @bradrn that you don't have to understand any deep mathematics to use Haskell. That's in fact what I was trying to say, in a way - the question "what does covariant mean" is a question about mathematics, and you don't need to know or understand the term to use Functors in Haskell. I didn't know how to answer that question without talking about mathematics, rather than Haskell - but clearly 2 people did and wrote great answers. Apologies if it sounded like I was trying to put you off, that was the complete opposite of my intention.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A *covariant* functor is just the normal `Functor` class:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

For instance, `Maybe` (as you noted):

```
instance Functor Maybe where
    fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a) = Just (f a)
```

However, there is another type of functor: *contravariant* functors. These are defined as follows:

```
class Contravariant f where
    contramap :: (a -> b) -> f b -> f a
```

Note that compared to `fmap`, `contramap` has reversed the order of `b` and `a`:

```
fmap      ::       Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
contramap :: Contravariant f => (a -> b) -> f b -> f a
                                         --   ^      ^
                                         --   look!
```

Now, does this crazy `Contravariant` class even have any instances? Well, yes. For example, here's the definition of a `Predicate`:

```
newtype Predicate x = Predicate { decide :: x -> Bool }
```

In other words, a `Predicate x` is a function which calculates a condition on an `x`. We can specialise `contramap` to `Predicate`s:

```
contramap :: (a -> b) -> Predicate b -> Predicate a
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
contramap :: (a -> b) -> (b -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
```

Basically, given a `Predicate` on `b`s, and a mapping from `a`s *to* `b`s, you can `contramap` to get a `Predicate` on `a`s. (I'll leave the implementation as an exercise.) Here's an example (untested):

```
hasMultChars :: Predicate String
hasMultChars = Predicate $ \x -> length x > 1

showInt :: Int -> String
showInt = show

intHasMultChars :: Predicate Int
intHasMultChars = contramap showInt hasMultChars
```

As it turns out, contravariant functors are a lot less common - and so a lot less useful - than normal covariant functors. So in practise, we leave out the 'covariant', since it doesn't add anything in most cases.

Comment: Thank you @DamianLattenero! (Although note that the Stack Overflow comments system discourages comments like that; could you please just upvote instead?)

Comment: Sorry @DamianLattenero, I must have missed that.

Answer (score 5):

A covariant functor is one where the “inside” and “outside” arrows point in the same direction.

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

A contravariant functor is one where the “inside” and “outside” arrows point in opposite directions.

```
class Contravariant f where
  contramap :: (a -> b) -> (f a <- f b)
```

...or, with proper Haskell syntax,

```
  contramap :: (a -> b) -> (f b -> f a)
```

That's generally an indication that the parameter-type occurs somewhere as a function-argument in the data type, like

```
data DepInt x = DepInt (x -> Int)

instance Contravariant DepInt where
  contramap f (DepInt g) = DepInt $ g . f
```

Conversely, if the argument only appears as-is or to the right of a function arrow, then it is a covariant functor. This is the case for most functors, which is why the class is simply called `Functor`.

Comment: In general, a co-'something' is a 'something' with arrows reversed.

Comment: @bradrn except when the “co” is followed by “variant”!

Comment: @bradrn That's not quite true, for example in graph theory `co-` as a prefix usually means "complement graph of this graph", so "cobipartite" would be the class of complement graphs of bipartite graphs. A complement graph is one with a complement edge relation, not one where any arrows are reversed.

Comment: @bradrn I'm not really sure I follow. "co-" is being used in a different context here. Also, [a "cofunctor" is the same as a functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732571/why-there-is-no-cofunctor-typeclass-in-haskell/34732721) (Wiktionary claims that "cofunctor" is a synonym for "contravariant functor" but, so far, that is the only place I have seen that claim and it has no citations. Maybe it needs to be updated?).

Comment: @David Yes, a co-functor is the same as a functor. If you reverse the arrows on `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, you get `co_fmap :: CoFunctor f => (a <- b) -> (f a <- f b)`, which is the same as `co_fmap :: CoFunctor f => (b -> a) -> (f b -> f a)` - the same as `fmap`. (Reflecting on my comment, I'm not even sure why I made it! Co-stuff wasn't mentioned in either the question or this answer, so the only reasonable explanation was that I was hallucinating at the time...)